# How to do non-blocking keyboard input on console app using Swift?

Tags: swift, console

I want to make a simple console game using Swift 5. I need to read keyboard input without blocking the game animation (using emojis). The game keeps on going while there's no keyboard input, but will react accordingly if there are ones.

I've seen some example how to do it in other languages such as C and Python. I knew Swift has Darwin module that provide many POSIX functions. However, those C codes seem incompatible with Swift 5.

For example, how to convert the C code below into Swift? There's no `FD_ZERO` nor `FD_SET` in Darwin module.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <termios.h>

struct termios orig_termios;

void reset_terminal_mode()
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &orig_termios);
}

void set_conio_terminal_mode()
{
    struct termios new_termios;

    /* take two copies - one for now, one for later */
    tcgetattr(0, &orig_termios);
    memcpy(&new_termios, &orig_termios, sizeof(new_termios));

    /* register cleanup handler, and set the new terminal mode */
    atexit(reset_terminal_mode);
    cfmakeraw(&new_termios);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_termios);
}

int kbhit()
{
    struct timeval tv = { 0L, 0L };
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);
    return select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
}

int getch()
{
    int r;
    unsigned char c;
    if ((r = read(0, &c, sizeof(c))) < 0) {
        return r;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int key;

    printf("press a key: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    set_conio_terminal_mode();

    while (1) {
        if (kbhit()) {
            key = getch();

            if (key == 13) {
                printf("\n\r");
                break;
            } else if (key >= 20) {
                printf("%c, ", key);
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        }
        else {
            /* do some work */
            printf(".");
            usleep(10);
            printf(".");
            usleep(10);
            printf(".");
            usleep(10);
            printf("\e[3D");
            usleep(10);
        }
    }

    reset_terminal_mode();
}
```

I expect swifty code to do the same thing in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The termios functions translate almost one-to-one to Swift:

```
#if os(Linux)
import Glibc
#else
import Darwin
#endif

var orig_termios = termios()

func reset_terminal_mode() {
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &orig_termios)
}

func set_conio_terminal_mode() {
    tcgetattr(0, &orig_termios)
    var new_termios = orig_termios
    atexit(reset_terminal_mode)
    cfmakeraw(&new_termios)
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_termios)
}

set_conio_terminal_mode()
```

The problem with `select()` is that `FD_ZERO` etc are “non-trivial” macros and not imported into Swift. But you can use `poll()` instead:

```
func kbhit() -> Bool {
    var fds = [ pollfd(fd: STDIN_FILENO, events: Int16(POLLIN), revents: 0) ]
    let res = poll(&fds, 1, 0)
    return res > 0
}
```

An alternative is to use the [Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch) framework. Here is a simple example which might help you get started.  A [dispatch source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource/2300104-makereadsource) is used to wait asynchronously for available input, which is then appended to an array, from where it is retrieved in the `getch()` function. A serial queue is used to synchronize access to the array.

```
import Dispatch

let stdinQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "my.serial.queue")
var inputCharacters: [CChar] = []

let stdinSource = DispatchSource.makeReadSource(fileDescriptor: STDIN_FILENO, queue: stdinQueue)
stdinSource.setEventHandler(handler: {
    var c = CChar()
    if read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) == 1 {
        inputCharacters.append(c)
    }
})
stdinSource.resume()

// Return next input character, or `nil` if there is none.
func getch() -> CChar? {
    return stdinQueue.sync {
        inputCharacters.isEmpty ? nil : inputCharacters.remove(at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Dispatch work on Linux too? I want my program to work on Linux as well. It's just a console game anyway.

Comment: @BeeJay: Dispatch is available on Linux as well. Please try it, it should just work.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it once I'm at home. Thank you, Martin. You're a helpful person. 

Comment: I just tried the kbhit() using poll() with the edited code above. It doesn't work. I will try the Dispatch, but it doesn't have the kbhit() function.

Comment: @BeeJay: I have tested both solutions on Ubuntu, and both worked. – The Dispatch-based solution does not use a kbhit() function. You call getch() and check if the return value is nil or not.

Comment: I'm on Mac now, I'm trying to use the poll() trick so I can get almost 1-on-1 convertion from c code to swift. But it doesn't work. It just stucks. -_-'

Comment: Could you tell what's wrong with this code: https://pastebin.com/nP1bBZgr ? Thank you.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer with this code: https://pastebin.com/vFSCHNB6    
However, it still has an annoying bug, it still prints the input although the term is set not to print it.

Comment: @BeeJay: Your first example (https://pastebin.com/nP1bBZgr)  does work for me. You don't see the output because stdout is line buffered (try to add `fflush(stdout)` after each print statement. Also that the return key gives 13, not 10 in my test.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. The code is now working without need to use Dispatch. Yes, it's 13 (\r) not 10 (\n). The code didn't work because I put the else clause at the wrong position. Once I corrected it, it just works. Problem solved. 

Comment: Just FYI, I have made ANSITerminal library that provide easy access to ANSI terminal features using Swift. Martin's answer helped me solving non-blocking input problem which is required to read return value of ANSI Escape command. Thank you, Martin. The ANSITerminal is hosted on Github here: https://github.com/pakLebah/ANSITerminal